# Why am I getting import errors while using "ant" command build.xml?

Tags: xml, ubuntu, tomcat, servlets, ant

I'm using the 'ant' command in a directory containing a build.xml but I'm getting errors with import statements. When it gets to this line,

```
    <!-- compile.gui -->
<target name="compile.gui" depends="test.properties,compile.api">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build.classes}"
        classpathref="gui.class.path" debug="on" target="1.8" includeantruntime="false">
        <include name="eu/lt4el/gui/**" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

it references a java file

```
    package eu.lt4el.gui;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import eu.lt4el.common.DocumentStatus;
import eu.lt4el.AppInterface;
import eu.lt4el.defcontext.Definition;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class LTStartPage extends HttpServlet
{ . . . .
```

and I get the following errors when it tries to compile the java file:

```
     compile.gui:
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/build/classes
[javac] /home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/src/eu/lt4el/gui/LTStartPage.java:3: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[javac] import javax.servlet.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] /home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/src/eu/lt4el/gui/LTStartPage.java:4: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[javac] import javax.servlet.http.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] /home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/src/eu/lt4el/gui/LTStartPage.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] public class LTStartPage extends HttpServlet
[javac]                                  ^
[javac]   symbol: class HttpServlet
[javac] /home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/src/eu/lt4el/gui/LTStartPage.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     protected HttpSession session;
[javac]               ^
[javac]   symbol:   class HttpSession
[javac]   location: class LTStartPage
[javac] /home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/src/eu/lt4el/gui/LTStartPage.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
...
...
[javac] 17 errors
BUILD FAILED
/home/ufuoma/Downloads/ltserver/build.xml:305: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I have Tomcat and JRE 8 installed and I'm running Ubuntu but the build fails. I don't know why I'm having the erros.
Thanks

Edits*
The class path is defined as follows in the build.xml file:

```
    <!-- class path for gui -->
<path id="gui.class.path">
    <pathelement path="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/common/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${lib}/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
</path>
```

Comment: In your build.xml file the variable `gui.class.path` does not have the Java servlet library or it points to a non-existent path.  Without more details that is all we can tell.

Comment: Do I put up all the code for the build.xml file?

Comment: How is `gui.class.path` defined in build.xml?  We don't need the whole build.xml file but you'll need to understand how it's defined and if it's dependent on other files.  For example, you may be loading properties from another file (sometimes named build.properties).

Comment: I've added the description of the gui.class.path from the xml file

Comment: Ok, so the build is dependent on the environment variable CATALINA_HOME.  For Ubuntu systems with the default Tomcat installed (i.e. installed via the package manager) you need to do a `export CATALINA_HOME /usr/share/tomcat8` in the same command line window that you're using to run the `ant` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class path needed to be set right according to my installation parameters.
It was:

```
    <!-- class path for gui -->
<path id="gui.class.path">
    <pathelement path="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/common/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${lib}/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
</path>
```

And my installation for Tomcat did not have a `/common`. So changing it to:

```
    <!-- class path for gui -->
<path id="gui.class.path">
    <pathelement path="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${lib}/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
</path>
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
$ export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
$ ant
```

Comment: And running "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh", I get the following: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.

Comment: Sorry - typo on my part - I fixed it.  But it looks like your Ubuntu is not in the normal place so I also updated the answer for that too.

Comment: I actually ran "export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat" a while ago. It works fine. But when I run "ant", I still get the same errors.

Comment: So where is the library you're looking for?  Read what build.xml says - it's looking for `${env.CATALINA_HOME}/common/lib/servlet-api.jar`.  Now I'll give you a hint - the "common" part of that path means that your build.xml is expecting the servlet library in a different place than normal.  So do a `ls /opt/tomcat` and see what you've got.  Next look in `/usr/share/tomcat` or `/usr/share/tomcat8` (if they exist).  You need to find that library and, hopefully, on one of the paths above.

Comment: `ls /opt/tomcat` gives: `bin lib logs RELEASE-NOTES temp work conf LICENSE NOTICE RUNNING.txt webapps`. `usr/share/tomcat` or `usr/share/tomcat8` does not exist.

Comment: So look a little harder - is there `servlet-api.jar` under /opt/tomcat/lib?  If so, then you need to modify build.xml to point to that.  If no, you have to keep searching.